# Is there a way to fix the width and height of a TextBox in Fabric.js and prevent them from changing with the text inside it

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I set the width and height for a TextBox in Fabric.js, but **the value of the height I set didn't work**. I don't know why. Is there a way to achieve a TextBox with a fixed width and height and prevent them from changing with the text inside it? Thanks for any help!!!

```js
var canvas = (this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c"));
canvas.uniformScaling = false;

var textBox = new fabric.Textbox("Freedom", {
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  width: 300,
  height: 200,
  fontSize: 20,
  fontWeight: "bold",
  fontStyle: "italic",
  textAlign: "left",
  editable: false,
  hasControls: true,
  editingBorderColor: "red",
  fill: "red",
  objectCaching: false,
  lockScalingFlip: false,
  borderColor: "black",
  lockScalingY: false,
  editable: true
});

textBox.setControlVisible("mtr", false);
canvas.add(textBox);
canvas.setActiveObject(textBox);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```